# на google поиск появилось не существующий линки на мой сайт

Tags: html, seo, hosting, google-search

На поиске google появилось такие ссылки на мой сайт:

```
сайт.ру/YwPrvkusleGclucbPweuirGnQ.html
сайт.ру/adGehhPshzdwGszrr.html
сайт.ру/PsfamtftoGhfcusxYzPbaxhYGJh.html
```

сайт не взломан, на хосте нет таких файлов,
но продолжается увеличивается такие ссылки.

В чем может быть проблема? Как найти причину такой ошибки?

Comment: А ты проверил может есть уже такие файлы? виросом может заразился сайт

Comment: Да проверил,нет такие файлы ничего не изменилось

Comment: Код статуса какой возвращается на этих страницах от вашего сайта? 200 или 404?

Comment: Открой сайт, сделай `view-source` и там посмотри есть такие ссылки или нет, может не файлы добавил вирус а испортил существующие файлы.

Comment: По запросу в гугле "inurl:PsfamtftoGhfcusxYzPbaxhYGJh" выдаёстя один-единственный сайт, он ваш? Если ваш, то факт - на сайте ЕСТЬ такие файлы.

Comment: возвращается 404

Comment: Посмотрель через view-source и тот же резултат, вроде бы все нормально

Comment: Если теперь возвращается 404, то значит через некоторое время ссылки из гугла пропадут

Comment: @andreymal, это на годы может затянуться :)

Comment: @AboHovhannisyan, а вас не напрягает, что гугль там по японски выдает заголовки страниц!? :) `Магазин Compomoto lnhvQYQclcuh 【высококачественные бомбы】`

Comment: @Visman ну вышеупомянутый мной запрос «inurl:PsfamtftoGhfcusxYzPbaxhYGJh» вчера ещё работал, сегодня уже нет :)

Comment: @andreymal, у меня он и вчера ни чего не выдавал. Первый непереводимый набор букв выдает и сейчас.

Comment: Вот смотрите так    site:brandonagency.ru

Comment: с гугла уже пропало, ведет только на эту страницу (стековерфло)

Answer (score 0):

Какой ответ сервера у этих страниц? Возможно у Вас не настроена 404 страница.
Кроме того.
Прогоните сайт через программу Xenu links - она покажет откуда какие ссылки у Вас стоят.

Comment: 404 сделано редирект на главную
Xenu links тоже не нашла такие ссылки